# how let mysql do not remove duplicate element of in parameter list

Tags: mysql

background

> Market colleague give me an excel file, have customer mobiles, and let me send some kind coupon to these customers, some mobiles are repeat that is mean should send more than one coupon.

there is a table have these data,

```
select * from t ;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | a    |
|  2 | b    |
|  3 | c    |
|  4 | d    |
|  5 | e    |
|  6 | f    |
+----+------+

select * from t where id in (1,2,1);
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | a    |
|  2 | b    |
+----+------+
```

you can see `mysql` auto remove duplicate id in `in` parameter list, but I want the effect like this

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | a    |
|  2 | b    |
|  1 | a    |
+----+------+
```

that is `in` parameter like a `list` not a `set`. 
So how could implement this in `mysql`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM t where id in (1,2);
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t where id in (1);
```

This will help you in adding the duplicate records in mySQL.

Comment: Shouldn't it be UNION ALL?

Comment: Yes I missed all. It is "Union all"

Comment: but you have to do some work to filter those repeat id, and how many times it repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Some workaround might be to do this that way:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_id (ID INT);

INSERT INTO tmp_id VALUES (1),(2),(1); -- etc

SELECT   t.* 
    FROM t
    JOIN tmp_id 
      ON tmp_id.id = t.id;
```